# i want to change URL of WordPress image or rewrite in runtime

Tags: images, multisite, url-rewriting, redirect, urls

this my images url and I want to change( https://oneclickwebsites.co  to https://oneclickwebsites.site)

https://oneclickwebsites.co/0373990752233591/wp-content/uploads/sites/489/2019/11/image-from-rawpixel-id-277250-jpeg.jpg

so it will look like

https://oneclickwebsites.site/0373990752233591/wp-content/uploads/sites/489/2019/11/image-from-rawpixel-id-277250-jpeg.jpg

all think remain some just need to change .co to .site

i check on the internet and find we can do this thing using htaccess

so i m very open with any solution

thank you

Comment: Those domains appear to be pointing to different websites. You can't rewrite a WordPress URL to a different domain if that domain is not pointing to that install of WordPress. Are you trying to rewrite them, or _replace_ them?

Comment: both are my domain and hosted in the same hosting the only problem is that when i clone site I get this problem image are upload in , site URL but don't know y bower call the image .co URL that y it shows missing page